# form_widget : Add classes to existing classes

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I want to add classes to existing classes with twig, when invoking the `form_widget()`-function, so I'd like to merge them. But when I use

```twig
{{ form_widget(form.field1), {'attr': {'class': 'foo'}} }}
```

on an object that already has some classes attached to it by the controller, it doesn't *add* the class(es), but *replaces* them. According to the [documantation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html) this would

> render a widget, but add a "foo" class to it

But the formulation isn't clear about, if the classes are really "added" or if they are replaced.

It seems that I would need to have a way to access the existing attributes/classes and merge them together with the ones I want to add. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `form.field1.vars.attr.class` and something like `str1 ~ str2` to merge the already given classes and your new ones.

Putting it all together you get:

`{{ form_widget(form.field1), {'attr': {'class': form.field1.vars.attr.class ~  foo'}} }}`

this works and solves your problem. Some background:

> According to the [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html) form.field1.vars.attr is a key based array, with a `class`-key. 
>   So you can access all existing classes in this way.